# Simplest way to write this logic

Tags: php

I'm writing a functional that calls two nullable boolean APIs. If either API returns true, my function should return true. If both return false, my function should return false. Otherwise, my function should return null. In other words:

```
true, true -> true
true, false -> true
true, null -> true
false, false -> false
false, null -> null
null, null -> null
```

Is there a simple/elegant way to write this? Obviously an if-else chain like this would work, but I think it's fairly messy, especially since you have to account for that `null` is a falsy value.

```
if ($cond1 || $cond2) {
    return true;
} else ($cond1 === false && $cond2 === false) {
    return false;
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can it receive something other than `true`, `false` and `null`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman no, both values come from APIs return typed as `?bool`.

Comment: You will achieve most simplest way by using ternary operator.

Comment: @Daweed Ternary is appropriate when there are just two possibilities, it's less useful for 3.

Comment: What you've written looks best to me.

Comment: Should read elseif, if you have a condition.  Your code above is invalid.  But other than that it passes your conditions.

Comment: Code should be clear to read and your solution is clear. Trying to make it shorter won't necessarily improve it. But your feeling is correct, it's a bit messy but it's not because of your if statement, it's because you have both false and null responses. You should try to normalize it if possible. Maybe you can refactor the code using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stick to what you suggested. One point of improvement is that you don't need `if - else` branching since you're returning. You just need two `if`s:

```php
function evaluate(?bool $cond1, ?bool $cond2): ?bool
{
    if ($cond1 || $cond2) {
        return true;
    }
    if ($cond1 === false && $cond2 === false) {
        return false;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, think this is the best it's going to get.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
return ($cond1 ? $cond1 : $cond2);
```

Comment: Almost. This will fail if the first one is `null` and the second one `false`.

Comment: You are right, i only read the table of booleans :D I should have read more carrefuly. What about =>

if ($cond1 === null || $cond2 === null) {
  return null;
} 
return $cond1 && $cond2;

Comment: `$cond1 && $cond2;` will short circuit on one false, so it's not equivalent to OPs conditional. (A conjunction evaluates to true only if both variables are true)

Comment: Crap ! I really miss a lot of particular cases ! :D

Comment: Here, I made a handy testing [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/MpVd8). If all dumps come out as `true`, then you have a correct algorithm.

Comment: You could do something like this `return $cond1 + $cond2 > 0;` lol. That is I mean after the null test you commented.

Comment: @Remy That won't work, because the `null` test is wrong, it will give `null` for the combination of `true` and `null`. The specs are that it should return `true` if any param is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `else if` block like so:

```
if ($cond1 || $cond2) {
    return true;
}

return !isset($cond1, $cond2) ? null : false;
```

You can simplify it down to:

```
return ($cond1 || $cond2) ? true : (!isset($cond1, $cond2) ? null : false)
```

But this gets hard to read and make sense of off.

Comment: True, but I don't see the overall improvement. The original feels a bit more readable.

Comment: Updated the answer a little bit.

Comment: Had to modify the one-line solution a little further.

Answer (score 0):

what about :

```
if($cond1 === true || $cond2 === true){ 
 return true; 
}else{ //check first and sec cond for falsing
    if($cond1 === false && $cond2 === false){
      return false; 
    }else{ //else null it
      return null; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Will fail because you use loose comparison. `false == null` will evaluate to `true`.

Comment: Im confused why you are so certain about not needing to check if the second condition is true? If $cond1 = false and $cond2 is true, your code will return null.

Comment: oops, did'nt think about that. wait let me edit again.

Answer (score 0):

Given your stipulations (and assuming each argument is one of: null, true or false) you could shave a smidgeon:

```
function foo($a, $b) {
    if($a || $b)                    return true;
    if([$a, $b] === [false, false]) return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below seems to be working, I have tried to logic using Javascript as illustrated below

```php
  function testMyConditions($c1, $c2) {
      return ($c1 === true || $2 === true) ? true:  ($c1 === null || $c2 === null ? null: false)
    }
```

```js
function testMyConditions($cond1, $cond2) {
  return ($cond1 === true || $cond2 === true) ? true:  ($cond1 === null || $cond2 === null ? null: false)
}

function runTests($cond1, $cond2, $expected) {
  console.log($cond1,  $cond2, $expected, $expected === testMyConditions($cond1, $cond2) ? '=> OK': '=> NOT OK')
}

runTests(true, true, true)
runTests(true, false, true)
runTests(true, null, true)
runTests(false, false, false)
runTests(false, null, null)
runTests(null, null, null)
```